# Designing an FIR notch filter with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, signal-processing

I am writing some code with Python using the scipy.signal library to filter electromagnetic data that is mixed with various undesirable signatures that I want to filter out.  For example, I have power line harmonics at various frequencies (i.e. 60, 120 Hz, etc....) with a width of only a few Hz that I would like to remove from the data using a notch filter.  Is there already an existing function in python where I can merely inform the code how many data points i wish to use for the filter, the center-line frequency that I wish to remove and the width of the transition band or do I need to design a filter from scratch?  If it is the latter I would greatly appreciate an example of notch filter design in Python to include window implementation to minimize aliasing.

Comment: Have you looked at [scipy.signal.firwin](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.firwin.html#scipy.signal.firwin) or [scipy.signal.firwin2](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.firwin2.html)?

Comment: There is an example on the Scipy wiki: http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.org/items/FIRFilter.html?highlight=filter

Comment: I posted a full example of notch filter in answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63038706/1886357

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few options for the solution on the `scipy.signal` website, but they introduce a lot of ringing, which will translate to artifacts in the convolved signal.  After trying many things I found the following function worked the best for implementing an FIR notch filter.

```
# Required input defintions are as follows;
# time:   Time between samples
# band:   The bandwidth around the centerline freqency that you wish to filter
# freq:   The centerline frequency to be filtered
# ripple: The maximum passband ripple that is allowed in db
# order:  The filter order.  For FIR notch filters this is best set to 2 or 3,
#         IIR filters are best suited for high values of order.  This algorithm
#         is hard coded to FIR filters
# filter_type: 'butter', 'bessel', 'cheby1', 'cheby2', 'ellip'
# data:         the data to be filtered
def Implement_Notch_Filter(time, band, freq, ripple, order, filter_type, data):
    from scipy.signal import iirfilter
    fs   = 1/time
    nyq  = fs/2.0
    low  = freq - band/2.0
    high = freq + band/2.0
    low  = low/nyq
    high = high/nyq
    b, a = iirfilter(order, [low, high], rp=ripple, btype='bandstop',
                     analog=False, ftype=filter_type)
    filtered_data = lfilter(b, a, data)
    return filtered_data
```

Comment: Thanks for the example!  You forgot to import `lfilter` from scipy.signal

Comment: So this would be raw time-series data we pass in, right?  Not fourier transform\ed or anything?

Comment: Could you also give some guidelines/advice for the parameters `ripple` and `filter_type`?  And band and freq are meant to be in Hz?

Comment: This is an IIR filter not an FIR filter.