# How to create a bandstop filter in python

Tags: python, signals, signal-processing

I have a .wav audio file and what I want to do is to filter certain frequency. The noise is at 1000Hz and I want to create a bandstop filter to filter the noise at 1000Hz.
I am quite new to python so I don't know if I am doing right. I think I did wrong but I don't know what's the right way of using signal.butter() function.

```
from scipy import signal    
b,a = signal.butter(4, [999,1001], 'bandstop', sampling_rate, output='ba')  
w, h = signal.freqz(b , a)  
plt.plot(w, 20*np.log10(abs(h)))
```

the plot it generated is definitely not a bandstop filter.

Comment: The question lack evidence of: *is definitely not a bandstop filter*.  Can you document this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a notch filter. It is implemented in the scipy.signal library: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.iirnotch.html

From the page:
"A notch filter is a band-stop filter with a narrow bandwidth (high quality factor). It rejects a narrow frequency band and leaves the rest of the spectrum little changed."

Comment: I posted a full working example of a notch filter in answer here as sometimes it can get funky: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63038706/1886357